# How do I ensure that a thread is started before another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have 2 threads T1 and T2. T2 should start its work after it gets a message from T1. Both T1 and T2 are started in main(). T1 can't start T2.

This is what I have so far:

```
T1:
    //do work1 which should be executed before work2
    lock2.notify()

T2:
    lock2.wait();
    //do work2 which should be executed after work1 ends
```

The problem is that sometimes T1 is started before T2 and T2 never gets the notify sent by T1 and waits forever.

Can I use any existing concurrency utilities to achieve this signalling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need some synchronisation mechanism between the two threads. Below is an example where I use a `CountDownLatch` for that purpose. I defined a class `SyncedThread` which gets a `CountDownLatch` passed in the constructor.

In the main method I then create two instances of this class. The first, `thread1` will run for 2 seconds, then signal the CountDownLatch and then do some dummy sleep for another 3 seconds.
The second instance `thread2` will wait for the CountDownLatch and will then sleep 5 seconds simulating work.

`thread2.start()` method is called first, then the `thread1.start()` with a delay of 500ms, but by using the synchronisatio you will see in the output that actually `thread2` is waiting for `thread1`.

```
public class ThreadStarterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        SyncedThread thread1 = new SyncedThread(latch, "thread 1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(getName() + " running");
                    Thread.sleep(2_000);
                    latch.countDown();
                    Thread.sleep(3_000);
                    System.out.println(getName() + " finished");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        SyncedThread thread2 = new SyncedThread(latch, "thread 2") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.await();
                    System.out.println(getName() + " running");
                    Thread.sleep(5_000);
                    System.out.println(getName() + " finished");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        try {
            thread2.start();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            thread1.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class SyncedThread extends Thread {
        private final CountDownLatch latch;

        public SyncedThread(final CountDownLatch latch, final String name) {
            super(name);
            this.latch = latch;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, whenever you use `wait()` and `notify()`, you should also have some sort of mechanism (such as a marker variable) to check to see if you're done waiting. From [the Javadoc for `wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--):

> […] this method should always be used in a loop:
>
> ```
> synchronized (obj) {
>     while (<condition does not hold>)
>         obj.wait();
>     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
> }
> ```

In your case that means that you simply never enter the loop if you don't actually need to wait.

That said, you might want to reconsider launching both threads from `main()`; from your description, it's not obvious why you're doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should make T1 waits while t2 has not sent the message.
Add a shared variable to represent the message and use it in a `while` statement.
And after `lock2.send(); invoke`lock2.notify();` in T2 in order to notify T1 if it waits for.

```
T1:
    while (lock2.isNotSend()){
       lock2.wait();
    }
    lock2.notify()
    //do some work

T2:
    // processing that sends the message
    lock2.send();
    lock2.notify();
    lock2.wait();
```